# DIV over youtube video on IPAD is not clickeable

Tags: html, css, ipad, youtube

I am developing a webpage for iPad and I have an issue:

I am inserting a youtube video (as iframe) and need a div to stay on top of it.

I already got it, using "?wmode=transparent" on URL of youtube video, and using z-index too.

On PC it works fine, works as expected, i can click on top div anytime.

On Ipad, when video is displayed for the first time, works as expected, visually div stays on top of video and i can click on div content.

When I click "play" button on youtube, video is loaded correctly; but when I click the div content, click is passed to youtube player, div is no longer clickeable.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
Iframe looks like this:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JQkActP-isE?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Top div looks like this:

```
<div class="topdiv" style="position: absolute; right: -410px; width: 400px; display: block; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 500000; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; ">
```

Note: Div becomes unclickable when video is played.

Comment: Do you have wmode transparent on both the embed and object tags?

Comment: it could be an issue with the focus. use JS to manually focus on the outer div. a code example could further elucidate the issue...

Comment: @kyleSevenoaks i'm including it as <iframe> there is no embed and object tags.

Answer (score 0):

I miss in your div the **`height`** attribute which may be the problem. If not, so you could try it with this method instead of iframe:

```
<object width="560" height="340" wmode="transparent">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/rUL0M__g1k4">
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/rUL0M__g1k4" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="560" height="340">
 </object>
```

Comment: Sry, I meant the **`height`** attribute ;/ This one is missing. I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks foy your help, but i'm not working on the project anymore, i can't found a solution and i can't test yours. But thank you ;)